# PHP How do I retrieve this value?

Tags: php, variables

I have a situation where I need to get the value of a variable, where the name od the variable is passed in a string in a second variable.

For example

```
$abc = 'the value I want';

$def = 'abc';
```

Where $def is the only variable name I can garrauntee being accessible. In this situation how can I get the value of $abc.

Cheers

Comment: @Thariama It bugs me - I frequently find the answers I get don't work out, which I think is due to my ability to ask questions well rather than the answers themselves.

Comment: ok, in that case and in case you find a solution you should answer your own question and accept it (sometimes this is helpfull for other people with the same problem). when the accept rating is low people tend to not to answer questions because they think they do not get rewarded

Comment: Why you can't use arrays here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo $$def;` does the job.

Use it very sparsely though, it makes code difficult to maintain!

Comment: So that is the same as (psudo) $ name is the value of $def? Just want to make sure I've understood!

Comment: @YsoL8: Writing `$$def` is the same as saying `$[whatever the value of $def is]` so in your example `$$def = $abc`. If `$def = "whatever"` then `$$def = $whatever`

Answer (score 3):

PHP can have [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), like this:

```
${$def}
```

It also, incidentally, can have variable object and function names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "$$def" for this.

Examples:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php